# Scroll complete tableView while updating tableviewcell

Tags: iphone

I have just three custom tableViewCell rows in my tableView. First and second are with label while third is with TextView, i want to autoscroll complete tableView as i type in TextView (3rd row) cell and there is no visible typing space. Can anyone help me providing some guideline, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When the text view delegate receives the didBeginEditing call, change the frame of the table view so that it's position is moved upwards. Wrap that up in a UIViewAnimations block and it'll scroll nicely.

Comment: Thanks Jasarien, Can you please provide a quick example for this?

Comment: - (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        CGRect frame = [self tableView].frame;
        frame.origin.y = -100;
        
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [[self tableView] setFrame:frame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

Comment: It looks like I can't format code very easily in a comment... sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasarien for your help and time, I will try this and let you know.